# Setting TemplateURL to a path to JSP in Angular JS 2

Tags: angular

I want to use jsp as a template file for Angular JS, since I am using JSTL to for internationaliastion of the pages.
In my .ts file I am specifying the path of the my jsp file but getting an exception

```
zone.js:101 GET https://test.com/WEB-INF/pages/blocks/test.jsp 404 (Not Found)
```

My **app.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
      //  templateUrl: "app/test.html"
         templateUrl: "WEB-INF/pages/blocks/test.jsp"

    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.
My jsp file will just have html templates and taglibs for internationalisation of the text.
When I specify the path of a html file here in templateURL, it works.

I understand the WEB-INF folder can not be accessed by browser and hence the file is not accessible. But I want to use jsp taglib for internationalisation and want to specify the path of the file in templateURL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use mapping Url instead of jsp page name for the templateUrl .

```
selector:"my-selector2",    
templateUrl:"/",
```

"/" is the mapping Url of the JSP page.(@RequestMapping="/")